# Decreasing the speed of Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an selenium integration test that launches browser and checks the webstore for any broken functionality. However the entire test runs too fast and finishes before I can even see which page is getting executed. How can I decrease the execution speed from my code. Currently I have following file that actually launches the test.

## AbstractSeleniumIt.java

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        urlProp = GenericUtils.loadProperties("url.properties");
        this.BASE_URL = urlProp.getProperty("webstoreUrl");
        xpathProp = GenericUtils.loadProperties("xpath.properties");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `EventFiringWebDriver`.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver slowDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver); 
slowDriver.registerListener(new ListenerThatAddsPauses(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

You will have to write your class `ListenerThatAddsPauses` which will extend `AbstractEventFiringListener`. In `ListenerThatAddsPauses` you will have to override methods from parent class and for example add needed pauses. Something like:

```
@Override
public void beforeClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
   Thread.sleep(timeout);
}
```

Here is a great [example](http://seleniumworks.blogspot.com/2014/02/eventfiringwebdriver.html)